# egress istio can't access to external service

Tags: kubernetes, istio, hashicorp-vault

I am currently trying to configure Control Egress Traffic to be able to access external services in https specifically with hashicorp Vault which runs on port 8200.

Below I attach the detail of my virtual service and service entry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: vault-se
spec:
  hosts:
  - vault.x.com
  ports:
  - number: 8200
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vault-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - vault.x.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 8200
      sni_hosts:
      - vault.x.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: vault.x.com
        port:
          number: 8200
      weight: 100
```

Any idea where my fault is?

Comment: In the VirtualService, the host does not match the host of the service entry: it is vault.x.net vs. vault.x.com. Is it on purpose? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry when I wrote the post I made the mistake of writing the host wrong.

Comment: Have you configured a  `kind: Gateway` as it mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-egress/egress-gateway/)? Could you also provide it?